# I've tried to achieve unified versioning of annotations, but what is the reason for the following error?

Tags: spring, annotations, version

### I tried to add an APIVersionHandlerMapping to override the registerHandlerMethod method and register it in WebMvcRegistrations to implement unified control of the annotation version, but I get the following error, what is the reason for this?

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[12-19-16:28:44.260] [main] [ERROR] [] [] - SpringApplication.java   [820 ] Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.isEmptyPathMapping()" because "other" is null
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
at com.yunmai.cloud.promptassistant.PromptAssistantApplication.main(PromptAssistantApplication.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.isEmptyPathMapping()" because "other" is null
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.combine(PatternsRequestCondition.java:241)
at com.yunmai.cloud.promptassistant.component.version.APIVersionHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(APIVersionHandlerMapping.java:35)
at com.yunmai.cloud.promptassistant.component.version.APIVersionHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(APIVersionHandlerMapping.java:17)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$2(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:298)
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:296)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:265)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:224)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:212)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:225)

`public class APIVersionHandlerMapping extends RequestMappingHandlerMapping {

```
@Override
protected boolean isHandler(Class<?> beanType) {
    return AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(beanType, Controller.class) || AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(beanType, RestController.class);
}

@Override
protected void registerHandlerMethod(Object handler, Method method, RequestMappingInfo mapping) {




    Class<?> controllerClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
    APIVersion apiVersion  = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(controllerClass, APIVersion.class);
    APIVersion methodAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, APIVersion.class);
    if (methodAnnotation!=null){
        apiVersion = methodAnnotation;
    }
    String[] urlPatterns = apiVersion == null ? new String[0] : apiVersion.value();
    PatternsRequestCondition apiPattern = new PatternsRequestCondition(urlPatterns);
    PatternsRequestCondition oldPattern = mapping.getPatternsCondition();
    PatternsRequestCondition updatedFinalPattern = apiPattern.combine(oldPattern);
    mapping = new RequestMappingInfo(mapping.getName(),updatedFinalPattern,mapping.getMethodsCondition(),
            mapping.getParamsCondition(),mapping.getHeadersCondition(),mapping.getConsumesCondition(),
            mapping.getProducesCondition(),mapping.getCustomCondition());
    super.registerHandlerMethod(handler,method,mapping);
}
```

}
`

Comment: you can refer to this [article](https://pdai.tech/md/spring/springboot/springboot-x-interface-version.html)